# Trouble with inheritance: Using pointers with class instantiation not working as expected

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error `undefined reference to 'vtable for Base'`. I don't know what this means as I am not using anything called "vtable". Also, I don't exactly understand how making pointers and `new Derived` are affecting the program. Can anyone clear this up? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Base { // undefined reference to 'vtable for Base'

    public:
        void f();
        virtual void bar();

};
class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        void f();
        void bar() {
            cout << "I am bar";
        }
};

int main() {

    Derived d;
    Base * b = &d;

    b->bar();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must implement `virtual` functions of classes you instantiate in order to compile. (or mark them `pure virtual`).

Just make `bar` empty in `Base`:

```
virtual void bar() {}
```

Or `pure virtual` (must be reimplemented in derived classes in order to instantiate them)

```
virtual void bar() = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I have a few questions though: When inheriting, what happens when you do `class Derived : Bar`, `class Derived public Bar`, `class Derived : protected Bar`, and `class Derived : private Bar`. Also, what does `new Derived` do?

Comment: @user6607: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c. 2. Allocating object on the heap. I suggest you to pick a c++ book

Comment: @user6607 to answer those questions, search stackoverflow, and if you don't find answers, ask. But only one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. First,  make the methods in `Base` pure virtual:

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void f()=0;
        virtual void bar()=0;
};
```

Second, you need to implement `f()`:

```
class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        void f(){}
        void bar() {}
};
```